# Sudden Ide Language Change in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, netbeans-8

I downloaded intellij idea from their website and whilst installation out of nowhere I got instructions in a language other than english. The same language was  reflected in my netbeans IDE, one of my reasons to switch to Intellij. The language seems to be inscrutable. I tried several trial and errors, but no result.

Since the UI is similar to android studio, and I have android studio, I tried to locate any language settings within android studio but couldn't get any. How did this happen? How can I get rid of this and be back to english?

Any help is widely appreciated..

[image: The screenshot]

**EDIT :**
My Environment variables

[image: My Environment Variables]

Comment: I think you should reinstall Java. It's a locale issue there

Comment: Check your operating system's language settings before you reinstall Java.

Comment: *I had issues with Netbeans and the language settings, so instead of trying to figure out that problem I decided to instead install IntelliJ and have the same problem," Doesn't make a lot of sense. *I have a problem. Don't make an effort to figure out why; just try randomly adding other software and hope the issue goes away* is seldom a good path.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I'm using win 10, I tried changing language settings, but no effect.

Comment: @KenWhite I said it's one of my reasons, not the reason per se.

Comment: In that case, reinstalling Java would be a good thing to try next.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Had there been a problem with Java, wouldn't it affect Android Studio too? My Android Studio is perfect..

Comment: Maybe or maybe not.  It's possible that you already have multiple installations of Java on your computer; and not all your IDEs are using the same one.

Comment: Assuming this is Intellij IDEA and Windows (and even if not, this is true for many other OS/IDE combinations), I doubt reinstalling Java would fix it. The IDE ships with its own custom JRE. 

The only way it could matter is if you had set a specific environment variable directing the IDE to use a different one.

Now an environment variable for language that both Java runtimes use? That's a definite thing to look for.

Comment: @JoeHz added screenshot. Yes, it has shipped it's own JRE versions.

Comment: It is maybe not the language but a font issue.

Comment: @Henry I tried to change it, but no result. The problem is even if I type in english, it is converted and shown in gibberish..

Comment: @Henry interesting observation. I happen to have encountered this just after installing many fonts on Win 7. Not sure how to debug this. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem (with Android studio) while my default windows 10 fonts were set to Nunito instead Segoe UI. After I revereted to Segoe UI everything works nice.